# Help understanding this sentence 謙遜を抜きにすれば/周りは非常に恵まれている

Tags: meaning

> 「 わたしも、これでも花も恥らう女の子なんですよ！？」
>
> 誠「不意打ちでキスしてきたのは誰だっけ？」
>
> 「あれは、まあ、好奇心で……にへへ」
>
> 誠「どうにも外の世界の基準がわからないんだよ。女の子たちが貞淑なのか開放的なのか」
>
> 「突然のキスも、壁ドンも、気障な台詞も、顔がよければ許されるだけってことじゃないですかね」
>
> **「そういう意味では、謙遜を抜きにすれば、誠さんの周りは非常に恵まれている気がします」**

In the above context I am trying to understand the final sentence but am not quite sure how to interpret it. To provide some additional context to the excerpt above, 誠 is from somewhere he lived isolated from the outside world most of his life except for the village he lived in. Its mentioned in the text that the girl he is talking to kissed him, but another girl also kissed him before this.

If I was to translate the final line it would be something like: in that sense, without being modest, I have the feeling that your surroundings are very blessed. However I am not quite sure how to understand this in context and would appreciate some help putting it together.

- I think the そういう意味では is referring to what she said previously 顔がよければ許される.
- 謙遜を抜きにすれば means without being modest, but what this means in context is not clear to me. I assume that she means if she speaks without being humble, but I am not sure about what, I'm guessing its to do with being attractive.
- 誠さんの周りは恵まれている is ambiguous and could either mean that the people around him are blessed, or he is blessed.

Comment: The meaning of the last sentence heavily depends on the context, and it still looks ambiguous to me after reading this entire excerpt. Who are considered 顔がいい in this work (Makoto or the girls around him)? Who are the aggressive characters who attempt キス, 壁ドン, etc? Or could you provide your translation of the previous sentence? Does this 顔がよければ許される mean "We are pretty so we are allowed to kiss you", "You are handsome enough so we are allowed to kiss you", or "You are handsome so you are allowed to kiss us"? What are the sentences after this 恵まれている気がします? Please provide the title if you can.

Comment: I suppose looking at it there is a bit more context I can add around why 誠 is talking to her in the first place which isn't clear from what I provided. He was trying to progress things further than just kissing with one of the other girls but she stopped him so he talks to her for advice (he has no common sense). It was originally the other girl he is asking for advice about that kissed him first and when the girl in the excerpt finds out she kisses him (the text references 不意打ちでキス) as well. So put simply the girls made the first move, but he is the one trying to go further with one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggested, 誠さんの周りは非常に恵まれている can possibly mean either "We (girls around Makoto) are happy because of you (Makoto)" or "There are plenty of pretty girls around you (Makoto)". The former makes sense when Makoto is regarded as a precious *ikemen* by the girls or there are not enough men in this community.

However, I feel the latter interpretation is more probable because 謙遜を抜きにすれば ("speaking without modesty", "frankly speaking") implies what follows is a sentence that can sound arrogant or overconfident. Thus the whole sentence *probably* means something like "Speaking of which (good-looking-ness), I hate to sound arrogant but you are surrounded by many pretty girls (including myself)".